# copy constructor with template class not getting called

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I was trying to write a sample code for implementing shared pointer [just for practice].
In this following example,

- why compiler is not complaining about modifying `other_T`
- And why copy constructor `SharedPtr(const T& other_T)` is not getting called ?
  Here is the code snippet.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  #define DBG cout<<"[DEBUG]"<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl
  class RefCount
  {
  protected:
      int m_ref;
      RefCount(){ DBG; m_ref = 1 ; }
      void reference(){ DBG; ++m_ref; }
      void dereference(){ DBG;--m_ref;    }
  };

   template <class T>
   class SharedPtr : public RefCount
   {
      T* m_T;
   public:
      SharedPtr() {  DBG; m_T = new T; }
      SharedPtr(const T& other_T){
          DBG;
          m_T = other_T.m_T;
          other_T.dereference();
          other_T.m_T = NULL;
      }
      ~SharedPtr() {
          DBG;
          dereference();
         cout<<m_ref<<endl;
         if(m_ref <= 0 && m_T != NULL ){
             cout<<"Destroying"<<endl;
             delete m_T;
             m_T = NULL;
          }
      }
  };

  class A{};
  int main()
  {
      SharedPtr<A> obj;
      cout<<"assigning "<<endl;
      SharedPtr<A> obj2 = obj;
      cout<<"END"<<endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

and the result is segfault.

Comment: For one, it should be `SharedPtr(const SharedPtr<T>& other_T)`. Also your copy constructor shouldn't be trying to modify `other_T`. And you should test if `&other_T` is the same as `this` before doing anything.

Comment: @Apprentice It doesn't have to be `const` though. Or are you just saying as general advice?

Comment: @remyabel Why did you delete your answer? It's correct.

Comment: @remyabel, yes you are right, it doesn't have to be `const`. But it is better that it is and would generally be a surprise if it weren't. His copy constructor looks like a move rather than a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem is that the copy constructor *is* being called--but you haven't defined a copy constructor, so you're getting the copy constructor that's defined by the compiler by default.

That copy constructor just does a member-wise copy. That means you've allocated one `A` with `new`, then pointed two `SharedPtr` objects at that same `A`. The first one to get destroyed deletes the `A` object. Then the second one gets destroyed, attempts to delete the same object again, and havoc ensues.

In the end, it doesn't look to me like much (any?) of this is going to make any real difference though. I'm pretty sure your basic design is broken. To get a working shared pointer, you have one reference count and "raw" pointer to the final object. Then you have N SharedPtr objects referring to that one ref count/pointer structure that in turn refers to the final object.

You're trying to combine the raw pointer/ref count into the individual SharedPtr, and I don't see any way that can actually work.

It also seems to me that the basic concept of what you've called a `RefCount` is really part of the design of a `SharedPtr`. As such, I think its definition should be nested inside that of `SharedPtr` (and probably made private, since the outside world has no reason to know it exists, not to mention being able to access it directly).

With those taken into account, the code might end up something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DBG cout<<"[DEBUG]"<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl

template <class T>
class SharedPtr {

    template <class U>
    struct Ref {
        mutable int m_ref;
        U *data;
        Ref(T *data) : m_ref(1), data(data) { DBG; }
        void add_ref() const { DBG; ++m_ref; std::cout << "m_ref=" << m_ref << "\n"; }
        void sub_ref() const { DBG; --m_ref; std::cout << "m_ref=" << m_ref << "\n"; }
        ~Ref() { delete data; }
    };

    Ref<T> *r;
public:
    SharedPtr(T *data) { DBG; r = new Ref<T>(data); }
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr const &p) : r(p.r) { DBG; r->add_ref(); }
    ~SharedPtr() {
        DBG;
        r->sub_ref();
        if (0 == r->m_ref) {
            delete r;
            std::cout << "deleted pointee\n";
        }
    }
};

class A{};

int main() {
    SharedPtr<A> obj(new A);
    cout<<"copying "<<endl;
    SharedPtr<A> obj2 = obj;
    cout<<"END"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notes: though this fixes at least some of the basic design, it's still quite a ways short of usable. It's missing the dereference operator, so you can't use the pointer to get to the value it points at. It'll break completely in a multi-threaded environment. I haven't thought enough about it to be sure, but my immediate guess is that it's probably not exception safe either.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Please vote down. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @neeru: Actually, I've up-voted. The design is flawed, but you've done research and a good job of asking about it. If somebody else makes the same mistake, I think they're likely to find your question useful.